# Value isn't passing to function on triggering change event, auto-complete jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made auto complete to a textbox as shown below,

```
<input type='text' style='width:100px;' id='tags'>
```

Here is the function which is loading auto complete on page load.

```
window.onload=function Search_Items() {
    var action = "Search";
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url:'Ajax.php',
        data: {action:action},
        success:function(result) {
            document.getElementById("Search_Result_Div").innerHTML=result;
            var temp=document.getElementById("Search_Result").value;
            availableProducts=temp.split("`");

            $(function() {
                var Product=$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableProducts,
                    select: function () {Data_Modification($(this).val());}
                });

                Product.autocomplete('option','onclick').call(Product);
            });                 
        }
    });
};
```

Here i just called a function and passed a value (value is what chosen in auto-complete). But here it's not passing value what i choose instead it's passing what i typed for searching.

What i inferred is, it's calling function and then populate the textbox with value what is chosen. But i need to populate the textbox with chosen value and then call that function. 
How do i resolve it? Please if someone got this problem before. Help me out please.

Comment: I found a solution. I rewrote this                                "select: function () {Data_Modification($(this).val());}" to          "select: function (event,ui) {Data_Modification(ui.item.value);}" and it's works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(function() {
    var Product=$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableProducts,
        select: function (event, ui) {Data_Modification(ui.item.value);}
    });
    Product.autocomplete('option','onclick').call(Product);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. I rewrote this

```
select: function () {Data_Modification($(this).val());}
```

to

```
select: function (event,ui) {Data_Modification(ui.item.value);}
```

and it's works fine.